# How to combine 2 django projects

Tags: python, django

I have 2 apps which i would like to combine, the first one is a login & register system and the next one is a file upload system how would i go by combining them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very specialized question that depends heavily on the code contained within them. Assuming they are set up as two separate forms in their own views, you may be able to put two separate forms on the same page but without seeing the code, screenshots, design plans or anything of the like, this is a very difficult question to answer.

I would like to have commented this instead, but I don't have the rep. Sorry for not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this and it would all depend on how your project is setup. Normally when you create a project in django you are forced to create an app, this is for modularity, the idea is to be able to have the apps be self contained entities, so in your case, you may want to move the app itself (not the project) from the upload system to your main login & register app, so just move / copy the "app" folder over to your other project, then you will also need to copy the settings and move them over. You also need to update the urls.py in your main app to include the urls from your second app.

Anyways this should give you some hints on how you could do this.